# Comparison of a string with given pattern

Tags: php

I am taking an input from the  user in form field. I wanna make sure that the given input should be in the pattern like "2012-xxx-111" i-e 1st four should be integers and there should be a "-" sign after that there should be two or three alphabets after that the "-" and at the end any integer value consisting of 3 numbers. Help me doing all this in php. Thanks
your help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) with a regex

```
if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z]{2,3}-[0-9]{3}$/", "Search String Here")) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
```

Comment: Or "/^\d{4}-[a-z]{2,3}-\d{3}$/i"

Comment: what do I need to edit if the last three integers vary in length for exapmle what to do if they are 2,3,4 ??

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regex for that.

```
[0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z]{2,3}-[0-9]{3}
```

This will match any number between 0 and 9 four times, following by a `-`, followed by 2 or 3 letters from `a`  to `z`, lowercase or uppercase, and finally another `-`  and 3 more numbers.

http://regexr.com/3bo81

In PHP, you can use [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)  to see if a string matches a given pattern.